# How to sort items in Firebase by the most likes

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

So i have made a app that i want to sort items by the most likes but the .orderByChild('likes');

orders them by the least -> most likes

Like the post with 0 likes it at the top how to fix that that the post with the most likes is at the top

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase Realtime Database you can use `orderByChild` keyword to get the items sorted in ascending order of likes. Unfortunately, `orderByChild` do not allow items to be sorted in descending order. However, there are two workarounds to this.

1. You can stores the likes in negative so that `orderByChild` automatically sorts it in descending number. So suppose a *post* has **10** likes, then you store likes as **-10**. And when someone likes, instead of *increasing* the *like* by **1**, you *decrease* like by **1**. In this way, even the value of likes is the same, you can sort it in descending order as (-10 < -9 < -8 ...).
2. If you don't want to modify the *likes* field, you can define another field (say **orderField**) and set it to a very high number. 
    Suppose you have two *posts* - Post1{likes: 0, orderField: 999999} and Post2{likes:0, orderField: 999999}. Now, when you *increase* number of **likes** of any post (say Post1), then you must also *decrease* the value of **orderField**. So suppose that Post 1 gets 5 likes and Post2 gets 2 likes then updated values of posts will be - Post1{likes: 5, orderField: 999994} and Post2{likes: 2, orderField: 999997}. And now instead of sorting by **likes** you can sort by **orderField** and this will achieve you the result.

Comment: Yes but iam using firebase realtime database how to do with that?